# Laravel : Expected type 'object'. Found 'array'. intelephense(1006). (VSCode)

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation

I am submitting a form thorugh ajax, form values are saving in the database and errors are showing without page reload, which is a good thing. As I am a beginner so i cannot make sense of this error. This error is not disturbing or impacting the flow of the application in any way. Thanks.

**Here's the error's image: **
[image: Code Image]

**Here's the code of the controller: **

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Products;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;


class ProductController extends Controller
{


    //Search Products
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $products = Products::where('name','like', '%'.$request->search.'%')
                    ->orWhere('id','like', '%'.$request->search.'%')->get();

        $output = "";
        foreach($products as $products)
        {
            $output.=
            '<tr class="border-bottom border-dark p-3">
                <td>'.$products->name.'</td>
                <td>'.$products->s_description.'</td>
                <td>'.$products->l_description.'</td>
                <td class="align-center p-5"><img class="img-fluid" src='.asset('images')."/".$products->image_src.'></td>
                <td>'.$products->category.'</td>
                <td>'.$products->quantity.'</td>
                <td>'.$products->price.'</td>
                <td>'.'
                    <form action='.route('delete_product', $products->id).' method="POST" id="deleteBtn">
                    z
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">'.'Delete</button>
                    </form>
                    '.'
                </td>
               
             </tr>
            ';
        }

        return response($output);
    }



    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function viewProducts()
    {
        $p_details = Products::all();
        return view('admin.products.view_products', compact('p_details'));
    }

    
    public function productVerify(Request $request)
    {

            $val =  $request->validate
            (
                [
                    'name' => 'required',
                    's_description' => 'required',
                    'l_description' => 'required',
                    'image_src' => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
                    'category' => 'required',
                    'quantity' => 'required|integer|not_in:0|regex:^[1-9][0-9]+^',
                    'price' => 'required|integer|not_in:0|regex:^[1-9][0-9]+^',
                ],
    
                [
                    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required',
                    'mimes' => 'Image should be a JPG, JPEG, or PNG',
                    'integer' =>  'The :attribute field should be an integer.', 
                ]
            );

            
        
            if ($val)
                {
                    return response()->json(['errors'=>($val)->errors()->all()]);
                }
                else
                {
        
                //  return redirect()->to('view_products')->with('success','Product added successfully');
                return response()->json(['errors'=>'Product added successfully, head to view products to inspect it. Thanks!']);
            
                }
                
    
               
          
            
            
    }


    //Uploading Images 
    public function validImg(Request $request)
    {       
       
           
            if ($request->hasFile('image_src')) 
            {
                $filename = $request->file('image_src');
                $filename->getClientOriginalName();
                $filename = time().$filename->getClientOriginalName();
                $destinationPath = base_path("/public/images");
                $request->file('image_src')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                $data['image_src'] = $filename;
            }
            
            return $data['image_src'];
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        

        return view('admin.products.add_products');
    }

    //Creating and Adding Products
    public function createProduct(Request $request)
    {  
              
                

               
                
            

                //Product Validation
                $validation =  $this->productVerify($request);
                
               
                
                $data = $request->all();
                $image_src = $this->validImg($request);

                Products::create
                ([
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    's_description' => $data['s_description'],
                    'l_description' => $data['l_description'],
                    'category' => $data['category'],
                    'quantity' => $data['quantity'],
                    'price' => $data['price'],
                    'image_src' => $image_src

                ]);
              
        

               
                 
                

       
}
  

     /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $product_edit = Products::findOrFail($id);
        return view('admin.products.edit_products', compact('product_edit'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //Product Validation
        $validatedData = $this->productValidation($request);
        
        $this->validImg($request);
    
        Products::whereId($id)->update($validatedData);

        return redirect('view_products')->with('success', 'Product details successfully updated');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $products = Products::findOrFail($id);
        
        $destinationPath = base_path("/public/images").'/'.$products->image_src;
        if(File::exists($destinationPath))
        {

            File::delete($destinationPath); //for deleting only file try this
            $products->delete(); //for deleting record and file try both
    
        }

        // $products->delete();

        return redirect('view_products')->with('error', 'Product successfully deleted');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`validate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) method on the `$request` object returns an array [(see API docs)](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_validate) containing the data that passed validation. If validation fails, a JSON response (which includes validation errors) is generated and returned to the client that made the request.

The code statement you're highlighting in your question is informing you that the variable `$val` is an `array`, however, you're attempting to access some data within `$val` using the object operator (`->`) as though it were an object.

If that code statement were to actually be executed, you'd see an exception message because of this (there is no `errors()` method on the `$val` array).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed description, can you suggest a solution to this error.

Comment: @merchant8 Yeah, remove it as it's redundant due to `$request->validate()` automatically returning a JSON response containing errors if validation fails. Just leave in your success response.